# Scrollr how to display none of other element?

Tags: javascript, parallax, skrollr

Hi I'm trying to set display none of my elements which are not visible, is there a way to this

for example now I have,

```
<div id="skrollr-body">

    <div class="home" >Home</div>

    <div data-0="transform:translate(100%, 0);"  data-100p="transform:translate(0%, 0);">Page 1</div>

    <div data-0="transform:translate(200%, 0);" data-200p="transform:translate(0%, 0);">Page 2</div>

    <div data-200="transform:translate(0, 200%);" data-400p="transform:translate(0, 0%);">END</div>

</div>
```

I would like when Page 1 is on top of home, home to be display:none;, I was looking through the internet to find something like callback function when the position is reached but no success.

Comment: Have you tried adding `display:none;` to the keyframes?

Comment: How can I do that?, I have tried to do in second div data-100p="transform:translate(0%,0);_home:display:none;", but this syntax doesn't work.

Comment: What is "_home"? Just add the property like with `style` attribute. ` <div data-0="transform:translate(200%, 0);display:block;" data-200p="transform:translate(0%, 0);display:none;">Page 2</div>`

Comment: Ok, now I understood what you want...why don't you add keyframes to "home" then?